# How to remove existing DNN ReCaptcha script reference

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, recaptcha, dotnetnuke-9

DNN V09.02.00 (366) adds the following script reference to every page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1541614764654/recaptcha__en.js"></script>
```

We are trying to use our own Google V2 Invisible ReCaptcha, and we have added the reference to our own script file (synchronously).
Unfortunately, due to the "async" attribute in DNN's reference to recaptcha, it loads after our own reference, overwriting its global grecaptcha reference.

How can we remove this script reference from DNN that we are not using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely that is being loaded by a third-party extension/module or the theme/skin.  DNN is currently not using ReCaptcha at all.

Comment: You're right, it seems that the recaptcha script from google actually loads another recaptcha script in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of DNN that is not a script that is loaded by the DNN Platform.

Do you have a third Party forms module by chance?  That could be the culprit.

Comment: You're right, it seems that the recaptcha script from google actually loads another recaptcha script in. Thanks.